# ffmpeg on raspberry pi

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Whenever I use ffmpeg inside a Python script using subprocess it doesn't work. Here is the code I am using:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video1 output.mkv', shell=True)
```

here is the error it produces:

> [video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x1a87220] The device does not support the
>   streaming I/O method. /dev/video1: Function not implemented

Comment: Pretty sure ffmpeg is not installed by default as the codec for it requires acceptance of a different license?  Not entirely sure that is accurate though

Comment: To rule out the pbvious does this work from the commandline?

Comment: yes it works from commandline. I am trying to run this on a raspberry pi if it makes any difference. I followed a tutorial to install ffmpeg on the Pi.

Comment: it has something to do with video4linux2 but im not sure what. I am a newb to python. can anybody help me further?